# How can I draw a specific GameObject into a texture in Unity?

Tags: unity, graphics, rendering

I need to draw only a few specific objects into a texture (with their material) and then use that `RenderTexture` as a texture for an another object. I think `Graphics.DrawMesh()` and `Graphics.SetRenderTarget()` would be helpful, but I'm not sure.

Ultimately I'm trying to create refractive water, which will refract only specified `GameObject`s, not layers. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use layers for this: put all objects that you want to reflect onto a 'Reflectable' layer. You can set the regular scene camera to render that layer like any other, but then you set the camera that renders your RenderTexture to only be able to see that layer.

Comment: Okay, it seems to be right. But if I have, for example two pools at the stage, then I have to draw both of them into each RenderTexture. So I will have a n^2 - n redundant draw calls, where n is the number of water planes.